# Thickbox - Won't close in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I use a button in an IFRAME to close Thickbox with this code:

```
self.parent.tb_remove
```

It works fine in Internet Explorer and FireFox but doesn't close in Chrome.

Comment: Take a look at your chrome inspector and post any error you see in the console so that SO users can narrow down the issue

Comment: well Im trying do that but I lost?

Answer (score 0):

Thickbox is no longer being maintained. Have you considered using a newer alternative such as colorbox? You may have more luck with cross browser compatibility.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/